# CSOM access to Virus Scanning Status

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, anti-virus

I am connecting to a SharePoint Online tenancy and interrogating a document library using CSOM. Is it possible to determine in code whether or not the anti-malware scan (which I know runs asynchronously) has finished scanning the file from the library that I'm interested in? I know that using the old sharepoint API you could interrogate an SPFile and see the SPVirusCheckStatus, but I can't see anything similar in CSOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a better answer, I am inspecting the value of the _VirusStatus field. If the file has been scanned it will have a value in this field.

Possible values (from the MS documentation):

- case "0": // No Virus detected
- case "1": // Virus reported by the
  scanner plugin but not yet determined if removal possible.
- case "2":
  // Virus reported by the scanner plugin which can be removed.
- case "3": // Virus successfully removed
- case "4": // Virus reported,
  attempted clean failed.
- case "5": // Virus reported, document should
  be deleted.
- case "6": // Timeout last scan.